# Why is javascript conditional failure happening at random times without error?

Tags: javascript, html, compiler-errors, conditional-statements

I am trying to update the text depending on time if daylight savings time is active based on what the localeString says. The conditional will sometimes fail at random. I have not been able to figure out how to log or store the failure in localStorage of the time and instance of the failure to see if I can deduce a pattern. Even if I could it would only log it if the page was loaded during that failure, not the instance that the code initially fails. Even when the target splice is equal to the condition it will still fail. Then for some reason it will work at another time. If you also are able to advise on how I can log the failure or how I can go about resolving this issue on my own. Thank you.

```js
//"use strict";
//Clock
//Declare variables
const clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("clock");
var easternStandardTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: 'America/Detroit',
  timeZoneName: 'short'
}); //Turn into string to splice the timezone;
var est = document.getElementById("est");
var dateString = new Date().toString();
var target = easternStandardTime.slice(23, 27); //Grab timezone from entire date string
var tz = document.getElementById("tz");

//Clock function
function updateClocks() {
  for (let clock of clocks) {
    let timezone = clock.dataset.timezone;
    let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      timeZone: timezone
    });
    clock.textContent = time;
  }

  //Read timezone to either condition and output that to the table cell and apply relevant href


  if (target === "EST") {
    est.innerHTML = "Standard UTC-05:00";
    est.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00";
    tz.innerHTML = "Eastern Standard Time";
  } else if (target === "EDT") {
    est.innerHTML = "Standard UTC-04:00";
    est.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:00";
    tz.innerHTML = "Eastern Daylight Time";
  } else {
    est.innerHTML = "<code>Error...</code>";
    tz.innerHTML = "<code>Error...</code>";
  }

}






// Update every half second:
setInterval(updateClocks, 500);
updateClocks();

console.log("Local Time: " + dateString);
console.log("Eastern Time: " + easternStandardTime);
console.log("Target splice:" + target);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Clock</title>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='cssindex.css'>
  <meta name="referrer" content="origin">

</head>

<body class="w3-blue-gray">


  <!--div for table-->

  <div style="width:85%;" class="w3-container w3-centered w3-padding-16 w3-display-middle">
    <!--table-->
    <table style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;" class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-center w3-mobile">
      <tr class="w3-white">
        <th class="">
          <a class="w3-link-display" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Town"><span style="font-size: 2.5rem;">&#127487;&#127462;</span><br>Cape Town, South Africa</a>
        </th>
        <th class="">
          <a class="w3-link-display" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan"><span style="font-size: 2.5rem;">&#127482;&#127480;</span><br>Michigan, USA</a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="">
          <a class="w3-link-display" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_Standard_Time">South African Standard Time</a>
        </th>
        <th class="">
          <a class="w3-link-display" id="tz" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone"></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="">
          <a class="w3-link-display" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B02:00">Standard UTC+02:00</a>
        </th>
        <th class="">
          <a id="est" class="w3-link-display" href=""></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="clock" data-timezone="Africa/Gaborone">
        </th>
        <th class="clock" data-timezone="America/Detroit">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div class="w3-container w3-mobile w3-center w3-padding-48 w3-display-bottommiddle">
    <a class="w3-btn w3-light-blue" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time">Time Zone Info</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For starters be more specific about what occurs in your "fail" and how you know it fails. Hard to help with such a vague problem description

Comment: The string `easternStandardTime` can be variable length because of stuff like 1pm vs 12pm, so slicing 23-27 will not always yield the timezone.  Instead of using the date "now" you could use a fixed date which will always have the same length.

Comment: That makes sense @James. Thank you! Could I also just include the extra digit in the splice and the || condition?

Comment: I forgot to mention that even when the conditional does not work, the splice in the console.log is being printed how it should be printed. Wouldn't that show a different string if it changed due to the string length of the date object?

Comment: the length of the string depends at what time of day and/or date you check

Comment: Thank you for your help. The string length was the issue, the thing that does not make sense is that the target splice value itself was correct even when the conditional didn't evaluate as desired. Luckily the part of the string I wanted was at the end, so I just did a -3 splice, and that fixed it.